# Use variable in postgres loop

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm having trouble when using the variable `arrow` in my loop. Postgres ignores the declared variable and reads it as text. How can I solve that?

I have the following error:
`ERROR: relation "arrow" does not exist Where: SQL statement "GRANT SELECT ON arrow TO test" PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 8 at SQL statement`

```
do $$
declare
    arrow record;
BEGIN
FOR arrow IN
    SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public'
LOOP
   GRANT SELECT ON arrow TO test;
END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL for this.

```
do $$
declare
    arrow record;
BEGIN
FOR arrow IN
    SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public'
LOOP
   execute format('GRANT SELECT ON %I TO test', arrow.table_name);
END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

But you can do that much easier without any looping or PL/pgSQL:

```
grant select on all tables in schema public to test;
```